# Using z-index with relative and absolute positioning

Tags: html, css, z-index

I created a JSfiddle to try and demonstrate what I'm trying to do. Excuse the duplicate use of video, but hopefully it gives the idea. https://jsfiddle.net/alexw129/z1nakg82/16/

I'm trying to use the `z-index` & positioning to generate a `PNG` image of window with a fire place (window background and inside the fire place is deleted so is blanked out in the PNG image). This is a link to the image

[image: image of a window scene with fire place]

I want to be able to place a video of snowy scene in the background of the image, which stays relative to the size of image as the screen moves (should take up `80%` of the screen).

I also want a video of a fire as background to the fireplace, which would need to stay positioned in the correct place relative to the image. Does any body have any ideas on how I could achieve this?

HTML

```
<!doctype html>

<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="normalise.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>

<body>


  <div class="main-header">

    <p> This is the header</p>

  </div>

  <div class="container">

    <img src="images/pic3.png">

    <video class="snow" autoplay controls>
                    <source src="videos/vid1.mov" type="video/mp4">
                </video>

    <video class="fire" autoplay controls>
                    <source src="videos/vidfire.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                </video>

  </div>

  <footer class="main-footer">
    <p> This is the footer </p>

  </footer>

  <video class="fire" autoplay controls>

                </video>

</body>

</html>
```

CSS

```
.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  // background-color:blue;
  height: 1000px;
  text-align: centre;
  text-align: centre;
}

.snow {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.fire {
  position: relative;
  width: 940px;
  z-index: 2;
  position: center-left;
  bottom: 500px;
  left: 715px;
  height: 350px;
}

.container img {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
  width: 80%;
  text-align: centre;
}

.main-header {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.main-footer {
  background-color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt this is exactly what you want to achieve, but it should be a good starting point. There is a few issues with your CSS. I will cover a few of them.

`text-align: centre;` should be `text-align: center;`. Although that only works with inline  and inline-block elements.

There is no such thing as `position:center-left;`. The posititon CSS property online accepts `static|absolute|fixed|relative|sticky|initial|inherit`.

You should use `position:absolute` when you want to position elements on top of one another or just to position it outisde of the document flow.

`position:relative;` is used on a parent element of an element with `position:absolute`. The absolute positioned element would then position itself relative to that parent element. Adjustments to the position absolute element can be done with `top,right,bottom,left` CSS properties.

Look in to the CSS styles of `height:0;padding-bottom:75%`. Varying the padding bottom allows you to retain a divs aspect ratio when scaled.

```css
.container {
  width:80%;
  position:relative;
  height:0;
  padding-bottom:75%;
}
.fire, .snow, .container img {
  width:100%;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right: 0;
}
.snow {
  z-index:1;
}
.fire {
  z-index:2;
}
.container img {
  z-index:3;
  max-width:100%;  
  height:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/qByLfxBJ/pic3.png">
  <video class="snow" autoplay controls>
    <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
  <video class="fire" autoplay controls>
    <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the detailed response and for spotting my CSS errors. I'll look into height and padding stuff. The code you've suggested is definitely a help in the right direction! thank you